# Position of "a lot"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Consider:

> Technology helps us with our everyday tasks a lot.

Is "a lot" necessary in this sentence? If yes, where is its proper position?

Comment: It's completely unnecessary to include ***a lot*** unless you specifically need to emphasis the idea that technology is ***extremely*** helpful in dealing with everyday tasks (as opposed to just "helpful"). But if you *are* going to include it, you should note that idiomatically, most native speakers would almost certainly position it straight after ***helps us*** rather than tacking it on after the [optional] prepositional clause ***with our everyday tasks***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct position depends on the meaning you want. The following is how I interpret "a lot" in various positions.

> Technology helps us with our everyday tasks **a lot**.

This means that technology frequently helps with everyday tasks, without specifying the extent to which technology helps.

> Technology helps us **a lot** with our everyday tasks.

This means that technology provides a great help with everyday tasks, without specifying how often technology helps. However, I suppose it is possible to interpret this form of the sentence in the same way as #1 is interpreted.

> Technology helps us with **a lot of** our everyday tasks.

This means that a large number of everyday tasks are made easier with technology, without specifying the extent to which or the frequency with which technology helps.

---

To answer, the other part of your question "a lot" isn't necessary in your sentence. If you remove it:

> Technology helps us with our everyday tasks.

Your sentence still makes sense, it just doesn't emphasize that technology is a great help.